# Do we need both [bone] and [skeleton]?

Tags: discussion, tags

In going through our tags page and doing some pruning, I found two tags: [bone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bone) and [skeleton](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skeleton).

Do we need both? Looking at the questions list, I *can* see arguments for keeping both, as there is at least one question there where [bone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bone) is valid but [skeleton](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skeleton) isn't. However, the two are very closely related and I'm wondering if we couldn't use one tag for both.

Comment: Maybe something as simple as [tag:skeletal-structure] would work?

Comment: @DJMethaneMan - that's the kind of thing I was looking for, I just couldn't think of a good phrase for it.

Comment: Right, because skeletons can be made out of things that aren't bone. Lots of fish do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say we need both. Because bone can be bone in general <strike>(including things such as nails)</strike>, skeleton relates more towards specific things such as Exoskeletons, Skeletal Structure, and undead skeletal creatures.

As such, we can have things that require Bone, but not Skeleton. (Eg: Question asking about bone claws)

Also, as Michael has noted, you can have skeletons that aren't bone.

Comment: Nails aren't made of bone... but point taken, bone can be a more general tag.

Comment: Aren't nails considered bone?

Comment: No... you may be confusing this with nails and hair, which are made of the same stuff.